# How to operate arducam PICO_SPI_CAM in ros2

Tags: ros2, package, build

I understand that drivers are required to connect external devices.

However, what arducam provides is an executable file.
spi cam git :https://github.com/ArduCAM/PICO_SPI_CAM

Also, the library file is as follows.
arducam git: https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino

I don't know how to put this together and hand it over to Ubuntu.

Please advise

Thank you